# Integrating paypal payment pro

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal

I want to integrate paypal payment pro in my website. Can I accept credit card on my site without asking user to go to paypal website for login and providing information. If yes, what is the best way to implement it ? any sample code or example will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) or [Braintree's](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) payment systems to be easier to integrate than PayPal's.

If you still want to use PayPal to process credit cards for users without PayPal accounts, check out [PayPal Payments](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products).